# How to call an image in REACT jsx element tag

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react js and will appreciate some advise. Trying to call different images for each `CarouselItem`

> is it possible to call an image in a react jsx html element tag?

i tried the below but no success:

```
<CarouselItem name="one" img src={iPhone} alt="iPhone"/>
```

This also did not work

```
<CarouselItem><img src={iPhone} alt="iPhone"/></CarouselItem>
```

below is my code:
Carousel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-elastic-carousel';
import CarouselItem from '../../components/Carousel/CarouselItem/CarouselItem';
import '../../components/Carousel/CarouselItem/CarouselItem.css';
import iPhone from '../../images/img_phone.png';

const breakPoints = [
  { width: 1, itemsToShow: 1 },
  { width: 550, itemsToShow: 2 },
  { width: 768, itemsToShow: 3 },
  { width: 1200, itemsToShow: 4 },
]

const carousel = () => {
  return(
    <Carousel breakPoints={ breakPoints }>
      <CarouselItem><img src={iPhone} alt="iPhone"/></CarouselItem>
      <CarouselItem name="one" img src={iPhone} alt="iPhone"/>
      <CarouselItem name="two" />
      <CarouselItem name="three" />
      <CarouselItem name="four" />
      <CarouselItem name="five" />
      <CarouselItem name="six" />
      <CarouselItem name="seven" />
      <CarouselItem name="eight" />
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default carousel;
```

CarouselItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

const carosuelItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="item">{ props.name }</div>
  );
}

export default carosuelItem;
```

Comment: What Error it give?

Comment: What is a `CarouselItem` and how do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach will pass a prop named `src` to `CarouselItem` component. Value of this `src` prop will be path to the imported image file. In `CarouselItem` component, you will need an `img` element and set the `src` prop as a value of the `src` attribute on the `img` element.

In `carousel` component

```
<CarouselItem name="one" src={iPhone} alt="iPhone"/>
```

In `CarouselItem` component

```
const carosuelItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="item">
       { props.name }
       <img src={props.src} alt={props.alt}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your second approach will only work if you use the `children` prop in `CarouselItem` component.

In `carousel` component

```
<CarouselItem name="one">
   <img src={iPhone} alt="iPhone"/>
</CarouselItem>
```

In `CarouselItem` component

```
const carosuelItem = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="item">
       { props.name }
       {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```